# C# Regex replace all word that start with specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I have an string and I wanna to replace all word that start with `$` and end with  (white space) with something else.

Whats the best practice for this?

Comment: Not being sarcastic but the best practice to post question is to show some research.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Asking for a best practise is just, well, strange since you obviously want regex and you seem to be quite clear what your task will be ;) (it also opens the possibility to close your question with primarily opinion based reason )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting from evident [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx); e.g. let's change these words into uppercase:

```
  string source = "$word $another skip $final preserve $end";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
      source,    // scan source
    @"\$\w+\b",  // starts with $, contains words symbols
      match => match.Value.ToUpper()); // turn into upper case 

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
 $WORD $ANOTHER skip $FINAL preserve $END
```

Comment: I try it several times but it doesn't work. I just replace with some string instead of `match => match.Value.ToUpper()`

Comment: @user3748973: if you want to put some *fixed string* instead of the words just change the lambda, e.g. `match => "myString"`

Comment: @user3748973: what is the *actual problem* (when given string - put here the example, please - the result should be - put here the example, as well)

Comment: ok, but if we have another word that is located end of the sentence, It meant we don't have any white space after that. how can replace this word too?

Comment: @user3748973: change `\s` to `\b` in the pattern (see my edit); and, please, edit your question since "...and end with  (white space)..." seems to be incorrect.

Comment: thanks, I change `$` to `@` but it doesn't work else. Is `@` specific character? how about this?

Comment: @user3748973: it is **$** which is *special* and that's why wants *escaping* - `\$`. If word starts with @ the pattern is `@"@\w+\b"`